# Fetch related items with Sitecore odata API result

Tags: odata

I have a field in an item, which is data sourced as a multi list.
When I try to access my item fields using `OData Service`, I am getting the multi-list field values as selected Item Ids.

Is there any way I can get the item name in single OData API call?
Also, I am not able to use `contains` property in the search parameter. 
Can someone give me a working example, if it is working for you?